# Is it possible to run a Win10 registry fix app against a registry on another disk?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

it looks like my registry got fried on my Windows10 Home PC as the as the server will not boot even to Safe Mode, the options in WinRE to restore/rebuild fail as well.

I have another disk which I installed Win10 onto and now have the server booted, I can mount my previous C: drive and see the files. Is it possible to run a registry fixer against the registry located on that drive?

Cheers

Comment: Windows will only allow you to mount a registry hive from another machine. If the problem with the registry cannot be solved manually within the Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE) then you are out of luck since the "registry fixer" cannot be run within WinRE. Easier to solve the reason the server cannot boot then attempt to do something that isn't easily supported.  *Most applications that claim to "fix" the registry do not actually solve actual problems.*

Comment: Registries change by the second on an operating system. Are you able to describe what "fried" it?  If not, or if the damage is too great, you will need to back up the drive with a bootable USB key and then reinstall Windows

Comment: Thanks, I have reinstalled. This time I’ll make sure the registry gets backed up. Cheers.